# wait for more than 5 seconds on a custom combobox dropdown list control causes win32 C++ application hangs in Windows7

Tags: c++, win32gui

I have a win32 application in that on **EditMolecule** Dialog there are three tab controls.First tab control opens **atom dialog**. On **atom dialog**, there is a custom combobox control, while user clicks on the dropdownlist of this control and waits for more than 5 seconds(in Windows7),the **EditMolecule** window becomes nonresponsive. The same application works well in windows xp.
Can anyone please suggest the solution to this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you are saying its custom combo box. Are you doing something with GetDC()? and if yes, are you releasing it properly? Are you also handling WM_PAINT?

Comment: Is it really working well on Windows XP? Bear in mind that Windows XP doesn't hassle you when applications become unresponsive, it just stops painting them. If you can move another application over yours while the dropdown is open, I suspect yours won't get redrawn. As the comment above mine says, ensure you're still handling Windows messages like WM_PAINT, as that's how Windows 7 ensures that your app is still responsive.

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick responses. I am not using GetDC(). When user opens dropdownlist, after 5 seconds the window is getting redrawn after that it hangs. I am not sure how to handle the WM_PAINT message.After moving to another application while the dropdown is open,it is not hanging.please suggest on this.

Comment: I checked WM_PAINT message handling.I am not getting any message in the atom dialog windproc, while the dropdown is open. I am not sure whats wrong with the application.

Answer (score 2):

When opening a dialog in pure WIN32, your main message loop is not running. You have to add a new message loop for the dialog.

Comment: I have a new message loop for the dialog(atom dialog message loop). However, while the dropdown is open I am not getting any message inside the new message loop.I am getting default messages in the parent window proc(EditMolecule wind proc). Not sure, why those messages are not delivered to the new message loop.